# onMouseOver="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" is not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, marquee

onmouseover attribute of the marquee tag is not working in google chrome. It works great in all browsers before 2 months. since january/ february onmouseover attribute doesn't work properly.

Could you help me please?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately this is true.

try this : `onmouseover="this.stop();"`
and `onmouseout="this.start();"`

Comment: It seems that setting the scrollAmount attribute doesn't work in Chromium anymore.  However, this.stop() and this.start() still works.